# How can I use permissions to control access to admin/config

Tags: users

For the purposes of a class, I am trying to use an alter hook and custom permission to control who has access to the admin/config page. Here is my code so far

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['admin/config']['access callback'] = 'user_access';
    $items['admin/config']['access arguments'] = array('admin blah');
}

function mymodule_permission() {
    return array(
        'admin blah' => array(
            'title' => t('access config'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Under permissions, I only have "administrator" checked. However, anyone can see the page. I want to make sure that only those with the "admin blah" rights can see it (and I have to use an alter hook). Any advice?

Comment: System->Use the administration pages and help, and System->Administer site configuration are the relevant permissions to use.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Why do you want to use a custom permission when Drupal uses already a permission for that page?